# angular-facebook module is missing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman

I'm using yeoman angular generator. The problem is: 
i added angular-facebook (bower i angular-facebook --save). This module exist in index.html and working good in dev mode, BUT when i build (minify js,css e.t.c.) my project, there is error in console:

> [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module testApp due to:
>   Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module facebook due to:
>   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'facebook' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Here my config file:

```
angular
.module('testApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ui.router',
    'ngStorage',
    'duParallax',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'faye',
    'facebook'
])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', 'FacebookProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider, FacebookProvider) {
    FacebookProvider.init('11111111111111111'); }]);
```

Comment: Is facebook module included before config file in minified js?

Comment: yes, sure. Checked just now.